# Manipulating an imported model with Papervision3D

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, papervision3d

This may be a silly question for people familiar with Papervision and 3D in general, but keep in mind that I'm neither of those, hehehe.

My question is, if I import a model with Papervision, is there a way to change its vertex position through code? For example if I have a head model and I would like to change it dynamically according to certain parameters, would that be even possible? Or will the model remain the same once it's imported? Just allowing stuff like regular scaling, applying materials, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Papervision is  no longer updated. You should look into Away3D or something similar. (see some more resources here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/games/gaming_engines.html)